# How to parse Retrofit list of list with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to parse this kind of response:

```
{
    "Data": [
        [
            {
                "Foo": "Foo",
                "Bar": "Bar"
            }
        ]
    ],
    "ResponseStatus": 1,
}
```

But I can't get it to work, the following exception happens when calling the service:

```
Failure(com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 10 path $.Data)
```

Retrofit interface:

```
interface FooService {
    @GET("getFooData")
    suspend fun getFooData(
            @Query("foo") foo: String): Response<FooDto>
}
```

Model:

```
data class FooDto(
        val Data: List<List<FooItem>>,
        val ResponseStatus: Int
)

data class FooItem(
        val Foo: String,
        val Bar: String
)
```

This works fine for other cases where there is only 1 list, but not here where there is a list of lists.

Comment: From what I infer from the error, the response is not how you think it is. An object is being returned where you are expecting a list. Have you checked the JSON response?

Comment: The problem was indeed something different. I was url encoding a url query parameter when it is not needed since this is handled by retrofit. The reason for this was that I rewrote old code that had this url encoding into using retrofit. This caused the server to return a different response causing the exception.

Comment: Is this the exact response that you mentioned above where you are getting respective error?

Answer (score 0):

I tested it out and it works just fine. I used Moshi though, not Gson.

```
data class response (
    @field:Json(name = "Data")val data: List<List<obj>>,
    @field:Json(name = "ResponseStatus")val status: Int
)

data class obj(
    @field:Json(name = "Foo") val foo: String,
    @field:Json(name = "Bar") val bar: String
)


val str = """{
    "Data": [
        [
            {
                "Foo": "Foo",
                "Bar": "Bar"
            }
        ]
    ],
    "ResponseStatus": 1
}""".trimIndent()

        val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
        val jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(response::class.java)
        val parsed = jsonAdapter.fromJson(str)
        println(parsed)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested using Gson it is working as expected.

Dependencies:

```
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
```

Unit Test reading from the json file containing the sample you gave to us:

```
class ExampleUnitTest {



    @Test
    fun getGson() {


        val rawJson = JsonUnitTest().readJSONFromAsset("test.json")
        val type = object : TypeToken<FooDto>() {}.type
        val fooDto = Gson().fromJson<FooDto>(
            rawJson,
            type
        )


        assertEquals(fooDto.Data[0][0].Bar, "Bar")
        assertEquals(fooDto.Data[0][0].Foo, "Foo")

    }
}


data class FooDto(
    val Data: List<List<FooItem>>,
    val ResponseStatus: Int
)

data class FooItem(
    val Foo: String,
    val Bar: String
)


class JsonUnitTest(){


    fun readJSONFromAsset(fileName: String): String? {
        var json: String? = null
        json = try {
            val inputStream: InputStream = javaClass.classLoader!!.getResourceAsStream("api-response/$fileName")
            inputStream.bufferedReader().use{it.readText()}
        } catch (ex: IOException) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
            return null
        }
        return json
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsed fine using Gson.

```
        val response =
"""{
    "Data": [
        [
            {
                "Foo": "Foo",
                "Bar": "Bar"
            }
        ]
    ],
    "ResponseStatus": 1
}"""
        val dto = Gson().fromJson(response, FooDto::class.java)
        Log.d("test", "Parsed: $dto")
```

Log output:

```
Parsed: FooDto(Data=[[FooItem(Foo=Foo, Bar=Bar)]], ResponseStatus=1)
```